# How can I get external jars added to the classpath of a executable jar created by GroovyWrapper

Tags: groovy, jar, classpath

I have a simple groovy script that executes some sql and plays with the results. It runs quite happily from Eclipse when I add the SQL Server jar to the classpath. However, I now wish to hand it over to a co-worker as an executable jar.

I found the ([GroovyWrapper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/WrappingGroovyScript)) script which works great, so long as the script doesn't have any extra dependencies.

I can put together all the jars manually and pass them via the -cp option, which works but you can't use -cp with -jar so I needed some other solution.

I tried adding an optional parameter to the GroovyWrapper script to embed SQL Server classes but that didn't work in the end as the SQL Server classes are signed and therefore can't be copied in.

I then tried to add a Class-Path manifest entry to point to the sqljdbc4.jar in the current directory. I have done similar things previously when creating standalone jars from java without issues but for some reason it still doesn't work.

I don't want to play around with fat jars, custom class loaders or the like if I can avoid it as the script is nice and simple at the moment.

Has anyone a solution? Have I missed something obvious.

Comment: Can't you add the jars where it says `// add more jars here` in the script?

Comment: Not if they are signed, well at least not when I tried it